# What is the differences between prepared statements and mysqli_query?

Tags: php, mysqli

I've read a book about PHP & MySQL.
prepared statement use binary protocol, but mysqli lacks this feature.
Also I read that prepared statements can be cached (their execution plan) and are faster than mysqli_query and of course safer?
when should we use prepared statements and when mysqli_query?

**EDIT**
Let's asume I have the below query:

```
echo "<table>";  
echo "<tr class ='tablehead'><td>Name</td><td>Location</td><td>Review</td><td>Image</td>  <td>Thumb</td></tr>";  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))  
{     
   echo "<tr>";  
   echo "<td>" . $row['user_fname'] . "</td>";  
   echo "<td>" . $row['user_location'] . "</td>";  
   echo "<td>" . $row['user_review'] . "</td>";  
   echo "<td>" . $row['user_image'] . "</td>";  
   echo "<td>" . $row['user_thumb'] . "</td>";  
   echo "</tr>";  
}  
echo "</table>";
```

Which approach is the best here?

Answer (score 4):

Prepared statements have some advantages, one important of them being to be much more foolproof against SQL injection bugs. I consider this to be their biggest advantage.

Concerning performance, one has to think about the costs of SQL parsing, query plan creation and result fetch phase vs. the cost of query execution: If I/O on the latter is dominating (as it often is), you gain very little from prepared staements or mysqli.

For simple repeating queries - as often used in the simpler part of webapps - the MySQL query cache works for queries with **the exact same and complete SQL text**, thus prepared queries will not make use of it. From my experience, this can more than negate any performance advantage of prepared queries.

Comment: So is it a better practice to use a combination of them?

Comment: Principally, every single query needs to be analyzed and proccessed according to this analysis. Ofcourse this is far from practical while developing maintainable apps. So basically I recommend to analyse a bird's view of your app, then decide on an implementation pattern.

Comment: What exactly does much more foolproof mean? Does that imply that SQL injections are still possible even with Prepared statements written properly?

Comment: SQL injections are a no-brainer for any kind of MySQL access if, as you said, they are **written properly**. It is much easier to get this right for prepared queries.

Comment: Can you elaborte on which "MySQL query cache" are you talking about? Are you talking about the cache in the db server running the mysql or the cache in the web server running the php?

Comment: The MySQL query cache is intrinsic to the DB server and is designed to speed up **repeating** queries by orders of magnitude: If a query is a) static and b) exactly (byte-by-byte) identical to a query in the cache, the result will be given back without any table access.